# Write and Read from file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ and maybe someone can help me.
When I read from a file everything is ok, but then the program is telling me this:

```
*_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
_Pnext was 0x6BD9AC.
```

Maybe someone knows what the problem is. Thanks!

`Struct.h`

```
struct Autos {
    string model;
    string year;
    Autos *next_node;
};

int main(){
    Autos car;
    Autos carTemp;

Fill(car);
PrintAuto(car);

ofstream fout;// Write File
fout.open(path, fstream::out | fstream::binary);
fout.open(path,ostream::app); Добавляет данные

if (!fout.is_open()) {
    cout << "There is no file there!" << endl;
}
else {
    fout.write((char*)&car, sizeof(Autos));
}
fout.close();

ifstream fin;//Read file
fin.open(path, fstream::in ,fstream::binary);
if (!fin.is_open()) {
    cout << "There is no file" << endl;
}
else {
    fin.read((char*)&carTemp, sizeof(Autos));   
        PrintAuto(carTemp);
}
fin.close(); 

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do binary reads and writes on strings or pointers. At least not successfully.

Comment: Do you know how can I fix that problem

Comment: You are trying to write a list or cars to a file. So design a format, for instance write the model followed by a space followed by the year followed by a newline. Repeat for each car in the list. Then do the opposite when reading, read one line, split on the space, the first part is the model, the second part is the year, make a new car from those and add it to the list. I just made all that up, maybe you can think of something better. But the point is that you have to do the work to output the data in the form you require. C++ doesn't do it for you.